# Marcar todas as checkbox com js puro

Tags: javascript

Coloquei uma function para marcar todas as checkbox, em um script que o Isac desenvolveu em uma dúvida anterior, mas ele não funciona em conjunto com a function, somente em um html estático.

```js
function all_check(marcar) {
    var itens = document.getElementsByTagName('checkbox');

    if (marcar) {
        document.getElementById('acao').innerHTML = 'Desmarcar Todos';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('acao').innerHTML = 'Marcar Todos';
    }

    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
        itens[i].checked = marcar;
    }

}

var json = [{
    nome: 'Pedro',
    data: '13/09/2017'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Lucas',
    data: '13/09/2017'
  },
]

var mydiv = document.getElementById("lista");
mydiv.innerHTML = "";
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
mydiv.appendChild(ul);

var escolhidas = [];
json.forEach(function(obj) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(chave) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add(chave);
    div.textContent = obj[chave];
    li.appendChild(div);
  });
  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.name = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.closest('li').classList.toggle('selecionado', this.checked);
    if (this.checked) escolhidas.push(obj);
    else escolhidas = escolhidas.filter(function(el) {
      return el != obj;
    });
    console.log(escolhidas);
  });
  li.appendChild(checkbox);
});
```

```css
.selecionado {
  background-color: #efe;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="all_check(this.checked);">
                <span id="acao">Marcar</span> <br>

<div id="lista">
</div>
```

Comment: Porque não posso agradecer quando no meu post ?

Comment: Agradecer uma pessoa é o minimo para se fazer, não é bla bla, são algumas palavras só

Comment: Então leia esse link para entender [porque removemos saudações e agradecimentos aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/851/28595)

Comment: Entendo, acho um pouco "frio" começar sem um bom dia/boa noite e terminar sem agradecer, mas ok.

Comment: Te entendo perfeitamente, também questionei isso quando entrei, mas depois você acaba entendendo. E como o site é para "quem fala português" o seu "bom dia" pode ser "boa tarde" ou "noite" pra quem está lendo,  enfim, dá uma lida no link q mandei, ele explica melhor os motivos, alias foi esse link q me ajudou a compreender melhor isso.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada, agora deu para compreender melhor, obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está no obter dos elementos para marcar como *checked*, aqui:

```
function all_check(marcar) {
    var itens = document.getElementsByTagName('checkbox');
```

Está a tentar ir buscar todas as etiquetas `<checkbox>`, mas as checkboxes na verdade são etiquetas `<input type="checkbox">` logo não as consegue obter.

Trocando essa linha para:

```
var itens = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
```

Ele já funciona, pois agora obtem os elementos com base num seletor de css, em que se especificou etiquetas `<input>` com tipo `checkbox`.

Para garantir que o array `escolhidas` é construído corretamente é preciso fazer algumas alterações. A primeira é apenas apanhar as checkboxes certas fazendo:

```
var itens = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:not(.todas)');
```

Que apanha todas as checkboxes menos a que tem a class `todas`, para não tentar guardar o correspondente à opção todas no array `escolhidas`. Isto implica aplicar uma classe diferente à checkbox que é para marcar todas:

```
<input class="todas" type="checkbox" onclick="all_check(this.checked);">
```

Para poder aplicar a mesma lógica no marcar todas e no marcar cada uma individualmente optei por criar uma função só para fazer isso:

```
function alterarCheck(checkbox, marcar, objetoJson) {
  if (marcar) {
    checkbox.closest('li').classList.add('selecionado'); //agora com add

    //apenas adiciona ao array se ainda não existir
    if (escolhidas.filter(x => (x.nome == objetoJson.nome && x.data == objetoJson.data)).length == 0) {
      escolhidas.push(objetoJson);
    }
  } else {
    checkbox.closest('li').classList.remove('selecionado'); //agora com remove
    escolhidas = escolhidas.filter(el => el != objetoJson);
  }
}
```

Agora esta função será utilizada em ambos os casos. Note que agora em vez de fazer toggle da classe de seleção ela tem de ser adicionada com `add` ou removida com `remove` com base no valor do check. Isto acontece porque você pode manualmente selecionar os elementos e de seguida fazer selecionar todos, mesmo eles já estando, o que iria fazer com que desmarcasse a classe de CSS.

Exemplo:

```js
function alterarCheck(checkbox, marcar, objetoJson) {
  if (marcar) {
    checkbox.closest('li').classList.add('selecionado');
    if (escolhidas.filter(x => (x.nome == objetoJson.nome && x.data == objetoJson.data)).length == 0) {
      escolhidas.push(objetoJson);
    }
  } else {
    checkbox.closest('li').classList.remove('selecionado');
    escolhidas = escolhidas.filter(el => el != objetoJson);
  }
}

function all_check(marcar) {
  const itens = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:not(.todas)');

  if (marcar) {
    document.getElementById('acao').innerHTML = 'Desmarcar Todos';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('acao').innerHTML = 'Marcar Todos';
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
    itens[i].checked = marcar;
    alterarCheck(itens[i], marcar, json[i]);
  }

  console.log(escolhidas);
}

var json = [{
    nome: 'Pedro',
    data: '13/09/2017'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Lucas',
    data: '13/09/2017'
  },
]

var mydiv = document.getElementById("lista");
mydiv.innerHTML = "";
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
mydiv.appendChild(ul);

var escolhidas = [];
json.forEach(function(obj) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(chave) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add(chave);
    div.textContent = obj[chave];
    li.appendChild(div);
  });
  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.name = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    //aqui chama agora também o alterarCheck passando os valores necessários
    alterarCheck(checkbox, checkbox.checked, obj);
    console.log(escolhidas);
  });
  li.appendChild(checkbox);
});
```

```css
.selecionado {
  background-color: #efe;
}
```

```html
<input class="todas" type="checkbox" onclick="all_check(this.checked);">
<span id="acao">Marcar</span> <br>

<div id="lista">
</div>
```

[Documentação para o querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Funciona, mas como eu faço para que tenha o mesmo efeito de clicar em uma por uma, preciso que salve o valor em uma array igual quando clico em apenas uma, obrigado

Comment: @PlanetWar "mesmo efeito de clicar em uma por uma", pode elaborar essa afirmação ? Não percebi muito bem

Comment: No código do post ao clicar em apenas uma ele salva o valor  e muda a cor de fundo, ao mesmo tempo exibe no console o valor do nome marcado, agora ao clicar em marcar todas não acontece o mesmo.

Comment: @PlanetWar Só vendo esse código especificamente, pois deve estar a fazer alguma coisa especifica que impeça de considerar as corretas.

Comment: O código está no post, clique em alguma checkbox e verá que o fundo muda para dar o efeito selecionado, e ao mesmo tempo salva o valor em uma array

Comment: Ok obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu testei com a alteração que você fez e coloquei um console log no final de return el != obj;
    });, ele grava na array mas o valor está em branco, e o fundo ainda não está mudando para significar que está selecionado

Comment: @PlanetWar Certo, já editei a resposta para acomodar esses detalhes que indicou. Confirme se está como era suposto